# wpa_supplicant keeping print message to screen

Tags: linux, centos, dbus, wpa-supplicant

I am start learning Linux(CentOs 5.5 kernel 2.6.35.13).

When I try to install a usb wifi stick(TP-Link TL-WN823N,and "lsusb" will show    **ID 0bda:8178 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.**.)
It work fine in the window interface( ctrl+shift+F7).
But when I shift to the command window(ctrl+shift+F1),and try to start wifi connection by

```
wpa_supplicant -Bw -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I found it kept print logs to screen before I type the command above.
I use

```
ps axjf |grep wpa_supplicant
```

to list all related process and find
there is a process start by user "**dbus**" with the command

```
/usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplicant.log
```

I dont know whether is this dbus' command that lead the problem. 
Below is the screen shot.
[kept logging msg:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RGYz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Partly fix the problem.
There are two things that make the wifi information keep on loging on the screen.

First, if you use NetworkManager, it will automate run the command under /etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant, where you can find the default command write there has no `-B` parameter which will keep the log in the background.So you can either add an `-B` to that command or stop NetworkManager and start wifi connection with your own command like in the question.

Second, when you install the driver, the default run status is power saving mode, so when you transfer data with wifi, you can see the screen keeping log infomation like "get into the pw_saving","get out pw_saving" etc.

To fix this, you can shut down the power saving mode like this:
create a file /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf with the following contents:
`options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0`

Or you can rewrite driver code to stop print the info to screen, which I still don't know how to do.